# Using WebApiContrib.Formatting.Xlsx stright from datatable/query

Tags: dynamic, datatables, xlsx

I have unknown data which I get it straight from query/datatable How do I use  [WebApiContrib.Formatting.Xlsx library](http://webapicontrib.github.io/WebApiContrib.Formatting.Xlsx)? which it asks me to have a model for every xlsx reports. I have tried to generate dynamic class from datatable but it doesnt seem working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be possible with the 2.0 release, which supports custom column resolvers and more robust serialisation for `ExpandoObject`. You can grab the prerelease version now on NuGet, and I plan to document the new functionality over the nice big break I have coming up soon.

Comment: Aaand this reminds me I never did have that break, and really need to document the 2.0.x release. ':-D